# Take jobs from jobvite with javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to take the list of available positions for a company from JobVite using javascript (I would prefer if it returned JSON)?

I would like to take 5 random open position and display them in a recruiting region on the website I am working on.

Comment: I didn't find any ... but I'm still searching :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if they have no API, I guess you're going to need to use cURL or something similar and then your PHP could return JSON encoded results?

Failing that, you might check out:
https://github.com/dylang/jobvite

Comment: Thanks, was looking at that myself. Saw I can use Xml.aspx to get XML responses. Thanks :).

Answer (score 7):

I can confirm that Jobvite DOES have an API, and it returns results in JSON! You need to submit a request to obtain an API key. (Look in the Category dropdown menu)

http://recruiting.jobvite.com/support/customer

Comment: More info: http://community.jobvite.com/t5/Career-Sites/XML-JSON-Information-for-Career-Sites/m-p/604/highlight/true#M2

Comment: Warning: The Jobvite API costs $50/month and their documentation isn't publicly (easily) accessible -- it's a huge PDF document.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  You'll need an API key and secret as blastronaut points out.  Then hit this URL:

> https://api.jobvite.com/v1/jobFeed?api=KEY&sc=SECRET&companyId=COMPANYID

The API documentation is here: [Jobvite Services API PDF](http://careers.jobvite.com/careersites/JobviteWebServices.pdf)

Comment: Do you have by chance current API doc url?

Comment: 404 not found. Any document where can I get for fetching jobs/positions ??